# write new content removing old contents

Tags: c++, c++11, mfc

Using wfstream i am trying to write some processed content removing the old contents from file.

```
wfstream cSrcFileOutput(m_cstrFile);
wfstream cSrcFileInput(m_cstrFile);
std::wstring cstrSrcFileContent;
....
```

cstrSrcFileContent has my content

I am writing as below :

```
cSrcFileOutput.write(cstrSrcFileContent.c_str(), cstrSrcFileContent.size()*sizeof(wchar_t));
```

The problem is it's not clearing the previous data. instead it's inserting processed content somewhere in the file.

I want the old content replaced with the new processed content.

Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clear data inside text file in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032970/clear-data-inside-text-file-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the file, you set the mode for how the data should be written to the file through the second parameter to the constructor

```
std::wfstream cSrcFileOutput(m_cstrFile, std::wfstream::out | std::wfstream::trunc);
```

where std::wfstream::trunc means overwrite existing contents (see [std::basic_fstream::basic_fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream) for constructor documentation).