# How to make open() truncate an existing file

Tags: c++, c, linux, posix

I m opening a file with `open()` function.

I want that `open()` function  discard the file content if it already exists, and then the file is treated as a new empty file.

I tried with the following code:

```
int open_file(char *filename)
{
    int fd = -1;
    fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Couldn't create new file %s: %s\n",
            filename, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

but I got the following error:

```
Couldn't create new file kallel333: File exists
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you want to remove or truncate the file

Comment: Have you tried with adding O_TRUNC flag.

Comment: @sas watever, the goal is to have a new empty opened file. I do not want to get this error

Comment: You could [open with the truncate option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17033060/1460794).

Comment: Add `O_TRUNC` and remove `O_EXCL`.  `O_EXCL` says the file may not exist — the `open()` will fail if it does.  The `O_TRUNC` says to truncate the file if it does already exist.

Comment: using `O_RDWR` is telling the OS to open the file with a mode similar to "w+" (if using `fopen()`)  what you actually want is O_WRONLY.  However, it would be easier to call `unlink()` or `delete()` or `truncate()` on the file, then call open with the desired parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please add O_TRUNC flag and remove O_EXCL.

```
open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

From open man page -

O_EXCL Ensure that this call creates the file: if this flag is
specified in conjunction with O_CREAT, and pathname already
exists, then open() will fail.

O_TRUNC
If the file already exists and is a regular file and the
access mode allows writing (i.e., is O_RDWR or O_WRONLY) it
will be truncated to length 0.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `O_EXCL` flag.  From the man page for `open(2)`:

> O_EXCL Ensure that this call creates the file:  if this flag is  specified in conjunction with O_CREAT, and pathname already  exists, then  open() will fail.

I suggest removing `O_EXCL`, adding `O_TRUNC`, and trying again.

Answer (score 2):

The manual page for `open()` says this about the O_TRUNC flag:

> O_TRUNC
>                 If the file already exists and is a regular file and the open mode allows writing (i.e., is O_RDWR or O_WRONLY) it will be truncated to length 0.  If the file is a FIFO or terminal device file,  the  O_TRUNC  flag  is
>                 ignored.  Otherwise the effect of O_TRUNC is unspecified.

Comment: That's part of it — but only part of it.  You have to remove the `O_EXCL` too, because if it is present, the system call will fail to open the file if it already exists, before the truncation has a chance to happen.  Note that it is a good idea to provide a link to the online version of the manual page you consulted if at all possible.  For Linux, you can often use http://linux.die.net/ as a source of manual pages — though there are many alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has stated, it's due to using the `O_EXCL` flag, when it should be the `O_TRUNC` flag instead. I just had this same issue. My best advice to anyone trying to use these syscalls that involve macros is to read the man page of your syscall. Understand what your macros mean before you try to use them and confuse yourself.

`man 2 open`

Answer (score -2):

I will tell you what this error is all about ! `Open` function will have a return type i.e some value will be returned after the execution of this system call (which in your case will be stored in `fd`). **This value will indicate whether the execution of the system call is a success or not**. When `open` system call fails, it **automatically returns -1 (to fd)** which you are already initializing in the first statement of your function `int fd = -1;`. Therefore, the statement `if (fd < 0)` is being validated as correct and hence you are getting that error. **Please note that you should not set the return values of the system calls, they are to be returned automatically when the program executes. What you need to do is just make sure you capture that value and validate it.** So please change your first statement of the function `int fd = -1` to simply `int fd`.

**Bottom line**: You are setting the return value of the `open` system call to -1 thereby **telling the compiler that its creation should fail at any cost** !! As far as the permissions are concerned, please refer to the other comments !! :)

Comment: `int fd = -1` does not set the return value of the open call.  It's unnecessary to set this variable before calling open, but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Answer is complete nonsense. This is not how code executes.