# How to write multiple lines to a output file in C?

Tags: c, file-management, file-writing, file-read

I am new to file operations like write/read in C. Is there a solution to write all printf() which is below, to my output text file? After execution I was not able to write all the lines to my text file.

```
for(i=0;i < n;i++)
    if(i!=startnode)
    {
        outputFile = fopen(myOutputFile, "w");

        printf("\nCOST of %d = %d", i, cost[i]);
        printf("\nTRACE = %d", i);

        j=i;
        do
        {
            j=pred[j];
            printf(" %d", j);

        }
        while(j!=startnode);
    }
```

Comment: fprintf(outputFile, FMT, ARGS);

Comment: Yes I tried but it only prints the last calculation to my file. I need all the i and cost[i] values in my file. also j value.

Comment: use freopen(fileName,"w",stdout); instead of outputFile = fopen(myOutputFile,"w"); 
Then use just printf() to print in file.

Comment: You should probably put the `fopen` before the `for` loop, and put an `fclose(myOutputFile)` after the `for` loop has terminated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [fprintf(FILE * stream, const char * format, ... )](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/) and pass the file handle to the function.

```
for(i=0;i < n;i++)
    if(i!=startnode)
    {
        outputFile = fopen(myOutputFile, "a");

        fprintf(outputFile,"\nCOST of %d = %d", i, cost[i]);            
        fprintf(outputFile,"\nTRACE = %d", i);

        j=i;
        do
        {
            j=pred[j];
            fprintf(outputFile," %d", j);

        }
        while(j!=startnode);
       fclose(outputFile);
    }
```

#### Edit according to your comment:

According to your comment update the mode you are opening the file to: `fopen("asdas","a")`

Comment: Yes I tried but it only prints the last calculation to my file. I need all the i and cost[i] values in my file. also j value in do/while statement.

Comment: Appending to the file should solve the problem. Everything else is unknown in your question. You should update your question accordingly.

Comment: thanks @ckruczek it worked. But I need something to clear my file. Because when I run again it always over writes and makes complex data inside of my file.

Comment: This has been answered alot. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815251/how-do-i-clear-the-whole-contents-of-a-file-in-c) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
outputFile = fopen(myOutputFile, "a");
for(i=0;i < n;i++)
    if(i!=startnode)
    {    
        fprintf(outputFile,"\nCOST of %d = %d", i, cost[i]);            
        fprintf(outputFile,"\nTRACE = %d", i);

        j=i;
        do
        {
            j=pred[j];
            fprintf(outputFile," %d", j);

        }
        while(j!=startnode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
freopen(myOutputFile, "a+",stdout);  //Redirect the standard output to file, "a+" - is for appending info if the file is has data before it is openned
for(i=0;i < n;i++)
{        
    if(i!=startnode)
    {
        printf("\nCOST of %d = %d", i, cost[i]);            
        printf("\nTRACE = %d", i);

        j=i;
        do{
            j=pred[j];
            printf(" %d", j);

        }while(j!=startnode);
    }
}
```